# Powershell Script with Procdump

Tags: powershell, dump, perfmon

So I have a system that runs pretty slow at night when running a report.  I've configured Performance Monitor to monitor the system.  What I'm finding out is there is a process that is tying up all the CPU.  I'm wanting to write a Powershell script that take a memory dump of the process id when a performance counter is hit.  This is what I have so far:

```
$programid = (Get-Process | Sort-Object CPU -desc | Select-Object -index 1 | Format-Table Id -Autosize -hidetableheader)
$app = "C:\procdump\procdump.exe"
$argument1 = '-ma'
$argument2 = 'c:\appdumps\ -accepteula'
& $app $argument1 $programid $argument2
```

When I run the script, I get the following result:

```
& $app $argument1 $programid $argument2

ProcDump v7.1 - Writes process dump files
Copyright (C) 2009-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
With contributions from Andrew Richards

Monitors a process and writes a dump file when the process exceeds the
specified criteria or has an exception.

usage: procdump [-a] [[-c|-cl CPU usage] [-u] [-s seconds]] [-n exceeds] [-e [1] [-b]] [-f <filter,...>] [-g] [-h] [
-l] [-m|-ml commit usage] [-ma | -mp] [-o] [-p|-pl counter threshold] [-r [1..5]] [-t] [-d <callback DLL>] [-64] <[-
w] <process name or service name or PID> [dump file] | -i [dump folder] | -u | -x <dump file> <image file> [argument
s] >

   -a      Avoid outage. Requires -r. If the trigger will cause the target
           to suspend for a prolonged time due to an exceeded concurrent
           dump limit, the trigger will be skipped.
   -b      Treat debug breakpoints as exceptions (otherwise ignore them).
   -c      CPU threshold above which to create a dump of the process.
   -cl     CPU threshold below which to create a dump of the process.
   -d      Invoke the minidump callback routine named MiniDumpCallbackRoutine
           of the specified DLL.
   -e      Write a dump when the process encounters an unhandled exception.
           Include the 1 to create dump on first chance exceptions.
   -f      Filter on the content of exceptions and debug logging.
           Wildcards (*) are supported.
   -g      Run as a native debugger in a managed process (no interop).
   -h      Write dump if process has a hung window (does not respond to
           window messages for at least 5 seconds).
   -i      Install ProcDump as the AeDebug postmortem debugger.
           Only -ma, -mp, -d and -r are supported as additional options.
           Uninstall (-u only) restores the previous configuration.
   -l      Display the debug logging of the process.
   -m      Memory commit threshold in MB at which to create a dump.
   -ml     Trigger when memory commit drops below specified MB value.
   -ma     Write a dump file with all process memory. The default
           dump format only includes thread and handle information.
   -mp     Write a dump file with thread and handle information, and all
           read/write process memory. To minimize dump size, memory areas
           larger than 512MB are searched for, and if found, the largest
           area is excluded. A memory area is the collection of same
           sized memory allocation areas. The removal of this (cache)
           memory reduces Exchange and SQL Server dumps by over 90%.
   -n      Number of dumps to write before exiting.
   -o      Overwrite an existing dump file.
   -p      Trigger on the specified performance counter when the threshold
           is exceeded. Note: to specify a process counter when there are
           multiple instances of the process running, use the process ID
           with the following syntax: "\Process(<name>_<pid>)\counter"
   -pl     Trigger when performance counter falls below the specified value.
   -r      Dump using a clone. Concurrent limit is optional (default 1, max 5).
           CAUTION: a high concurrency value may impact system performance.
           - Windows 7   : Uses Reflection. OS doesn't support -e.
           - Windows 8.0 : Uses Reflection. OS doesn't support -e.
           - Windows 8.1+: Uses PSS. All trigger types are supported.
   -s      Consecutive seconds before dump is written (default is 10).
   -t      Write a dump when the process terminates.
   -u      Treat CPU usage relative to a single core (used with -c).
           As the only option, Uninstalls ProcDump as the postmortem debugger.
   -w      Wait for the specified process to launch if it's not running.
   -x      Launch the specified image with optional arguments. 
           If it is a Store Application or Package, ProcDump will start
           on the next activation (only).
   -64     By default ProcDump will capture a 32-bit dump of a 32-bit process
           when running on 64-bit Windows. This option overrides to create a
           64-bit dump. Only use for WOW64 subsystem debugging.

Use the -accepteula command line option to automatically accept the
Sysinternals license agreement.

Use -? -e to see example command lines.

If you omit the dump file name, it defaults to <processname>_<datetime>.dmp.
```

If I run this command manually:

```
C:\procdump>procdump.exe -ma 5264 c:\appdumps\ -accepteula
```

I get this output:

```
ProcDump v7.1 - Writes process dump files
Copyright (C) 2009-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
With contributions from Andrew Richards

[12:25:06] Dump 1 initiated: c:\appdumps\notepad.exe_151212_122506.dmp
[12:25:07] Dump 1 writing: Estimated dump file size is 53 MB.
[12:25:07] Dump 1 complete: 53 MB written in 1.0 seconds
[12:25:08] Dump count reached.
```

I know the command works, just wondering what isn't getting passed correctly.  Is there a way to setup a log to determine what exactly is being passed to procdump when it runs?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting here two things into a single argument:

```
$argument2 = 'c:\appdumps\ -accepteula'
```

Powershell doesn't split that into two arguments, and ProcessDump doesn't understand that as a single argument. So, you need to put each argument into individual variables.